# Python - Create a new column in the DataFrame based on some conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with some data as shown below, the exit column marks the exit flag of a customer on MonthEnd date. So, wherever it is 1, the customer has left in that month.

```
index    group      date    exit 
  0        A       Jan-22     0  
  1        A       Feb-22     0 
  2        A       Mar-22     0 
  3        A       Apr-22     0 
  5        A       May-22     0 
  6        A       Jun-22     0 
  7        A       Jul-22     0 
  8        A       Aug-22     0 
  9        A       Sep-22     1 
  6        B       Mar-21     0 
  7        B       Apr-21     0 
  8        B       May-21     0 
  9        B       Jun-21     0 
  10       B       Jul-21     0 
  11       B       Aug-21     0 
  12       B       Sep-21     0 
  13       B       Oct-21     1 
  14       C       Jan-23     0 
  15       C       Feb-23     0 
  16       C       Mar-23     1 
  17       D       Jul-23     0 
  18       D       Aug-23     1
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to make a new column "exit_6months", the condition is to mark exit flag 6 months before the actual exit. so the result will be as below.

For C and D group, there are not enough months to go back to 6 months as the customer made exit soon, so all the values will be 1 for them.

I tried using relativedelta but could not acheive this, is there a way to do this? Thank you :)

```
index    group      date    exit   exit_6m  
  0        A       Jan-22     0      0 
  1        A       Feb-22     0      0
  2        A       Mar-22     0      0
  3        A       Apr-22     0      1
  5        A       May-22     0      1
  6        A       Jun-22     0      1
  7        A       Jul-22     0      1
  8        A       Aug-22     0      1
  9        A       Sep-22     1      1
  6        B       Mar-21     0      0
  7        B       Apr-21     0      0
  8        B       May-21     0      1
  9        B       Jun-21     0      1
  10       B       Jul-21     0      1
  11       B       Aug-21     0      1
  12       B       Sep-21     0      1
  13       B       Oct-21     1      1
  14       C       Jan-23     0      1
  15       C       Feb-23     0      1
  16       C       Mar-23     1      1
  17       D       Jul-23     0      1
  18       D       Aug-23     1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask the zero's then backfill the values with a limit for 6 months per group and fill the remaining null values with zeros

```
df['exit_6M'] = (
    df['exit']
    .where(df['exit'].eq(1))
    .groupby(df['group'])
    .bfill(limit=5)
    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
```

---

```
    index group    date  exit  exit_6M
0       0     A  Jan-22     0        0
1       1     A  Feb-22     0        0
2       2     A  Mar-22     0        0
3       3     A  Apr-22     0        1
4       5     A  May-22     0        1
5       6     A  Jun-22     0        1
6       7     A  Jul-22     0        1
7       8     A  Aug-22     0        1
8       9     A  Sep-22     1        1
9       6     B  Mar-21     0        0
10      7     B  Apr-21     0        0
11      8     B  May-21     0        1
12      9     B  Jun-21     0        1
13     10     B  Jul-21     0        1
14     11     B  Aug-21     0        1
15     12     B  Sep-21     0        1
16     13     B  Oct-21     1        1
17     14     C  Jan-23     0        1
18     15     C  Feb-23     0        1
19     16     C  Mar-23     1        1
20     17     D  Jul-23     0        1
21     18     D  Aug-23     1        1
```

Comment: I can;t imagine it was this simple, I was trying to do it offset 6 months using relativedelta. Thank you so much, let me try this way

Comment: I could not see any difference in the results after sampling between your first answer and the new update using groupby, anything you want to specify if I am missing?

Comment: its just a `.groupby(df['group'])` . we want to backfill per group otherwise the backward filled values from one group can spill into other

Answer (score 1):

The following code might be helpful:

```
import pandas as pd
    
    # Create the dataframe
    data = {
        'group': ['A']*9 + ['B']*8 + ['C']*3 + ['D']*2,
        'date': ['Jan-22', 'Feb-22', 'Mar-22', 'Apr-22', 'May-22', 'Jun-22', 'Jul-22', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-22',
                 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'May-21', 'Jun-21', 'Jul-21', 'Aug-21', 'Sep-21', 'Oct-21', 
                 'Jan-23', 'Feb-23', 'Mar-23', 'Jul-23', 'Aug-23'],
        'exit': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')
    
    def mark_prior_6_months(group):
        exit_indices = group[group['exit'] == 1].index
        for idx in exit_indices:
            # We use the date frequency 'M' for months
            start_date = group.loc[idx, 'date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=5)
            mask = (group['date'] >= start_date) & (group['date'] < group.loc[idx, 'date'])
            group.loc[mask, 'exit'] = 1
        return group
    
    # Apply the function to each group
    df = df.groupby('group').apply(mark_prior_6_months)
    
    print(df)


group       date  exit
group                          
A     0      A 2022-01-01     0
      1      A 2022-02-01     0
      2      A 2022-03-01     0
      3      A 2022-04-01     1
      4      A 2022-05-01     1
      5      A 2022-06-01     1
      6      A 2022-07-01     1
      7      A 2022-08-01     1
      8      A 2022-09-01     1
B     9      B 2021-03-01     0
      10     B 2021-04-01     0
      11     B 2021-05-01     1
      12     B 2021-06-01     1
      13     B 2021-07-01     1
      14     B 2021-08-01     1
      15     B 2021-09-01     1
      16     B 2021-10-01     1
C     17     C 2023-01-01     1
      18     C 2023-02-01     1
      19     C 2023-03-01     1
D     20     D 2023-07-01     1
      21     D 2023-08-01     1
```